# problem writing a tutorial in rosserial_xbee

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write my first tutorial at rosserial_xbee and I am facing a problem while trying to write a tutorial in rosserial_xbee.
whenever I write a few lines and preview it, it does give correct output but when I save the changes, it shows error:

TextCha: Wrong answer! Go back and try again...

help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73141/problem-writing-a-tutorial-in-rosserial_xbee/) by [saurabh_shandilya](https://answers.ros.org/users/5342/saurabh_shandilya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also unable to answer the TextCha question, I'm trying to update a page I created in 2014.

The TextCha Question appears to be "No Spammers :P"
Did you find the answer?

Edit: status.ros.org says editing is currently disabled due to spammers

---

Originally posted by [Moriarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/9466/moriarty/) with karma: 16 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0